# How to quit the page if i type hello world on google search using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, mozilla

Hi guys I want to quit the page afte I type "Hello World" in google search using firefox browser and selenium

```
WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    SimpleSelenium ss = new SimpleSelenium();
    ss.openBrowser();
    ss.getPage();
    ss.quitPage();
}

private void openBrowser() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}

private void quitPage() {
    driver.quit();

}

private void getPage() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

}
```

Comment: where is your test class, before and after methods?.You have written a standalone java program

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is the issue?

Comment: I want to quit the page after typing hello world on a google search

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Create a Junit test class
2) Initialize the driver in your setup method like 
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//Download chromeDriver.exe file and point to location where you have installed the like as you mentioned. `driver.System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");`
3) Create a test method with your business logic to type hello world
3) Create After and Before Class annotations for the methods .In After class annotation method you can write driver.quit.
```

You can refer to following link for more clarity
https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Comment: Bro you can use any driver .Its your wish .But logic remains same.I just gave a sample code:)

Comment: Can you pls go through this link http://www.absofttrainings.com/how-to-use-new-firefoxdriver-geckodriver-or-marionette-with-selenium-3/

Answer (score 0):

I am Added sample format which is written Using java and testNG..Here Every time First before method will run then 1st test case will execute then after method will work then again before method work then next test case......In this way you can manage your test case and it will also generate Report also.[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/) you will get better explanation.

```
public class GoogleTest {
        FirefoxDriver driver;

        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp1() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\ToolsQA\\trunk\\Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }


        @Test
        public void GoogleInputField() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.out.println("Hello world");
            //Write Your test case for test case 1


        }
        @Test
        public void google suggestion() throws InterruptedException {

            //Write Your test case for test case 1


        }

        @AfterMethod
        public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {

            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

> Dont forget to add Firefox driver on gecko.driver path

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to open the browser using selenium, load google and then listen till you MANUALLY enter "hello world" in the input box. The method `listenForHelloWorld()` will do that.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    SimpleSelenium ss = new SimpleSelenium();
    ss.openBrowser();
    ss.getPage();
    ss.listenForHelloWorld();
    ss.quitPage();
}

private void listenForHelloWorld() {
    // Get the search field    
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    int count = 1;
    while (count++ < 20) {
        // if search field value is "hellwo world" break loop which will eventallu lead to `quit()` as it is the next method to exit.
        if (searchField.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("hello world")) {
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
}
```

If you are asking how to enter "hello world" in browser automatically use below.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("hello world");
```